# Adding calls to Google Analytics into Magnific-popup

Tags: google-analytics, magnific-popup

I'd like to add calls to Google Analytics to record when picture in a gallery are gotten to via the "Next" or "Prev" buttons.

I tried to capture when those buttons are pushed using this code:

```
$(".lightbox").magnificPopup({
    type:'image',
    gallery:{
        enabled:true
    },
    callbacks: {
        next: function() {
            alert('Next');
        },
        prev: function () {
            alert('Prev');
        }
    }

});
```

I don't get the alerts when I press the buttons. Obviously, I missed something... :)

Ken

Comment: are `next` and `prev` valid callbacks?

Comment: I figured it out. The correct callback to use is markupParse. It works very nicely.